# Special and accented characters in mysql generates bad symbols in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding

my collation is set to utf8_general_ci both on tables and fields. My HTML has the `META` tag that changes the charset to UTF8.

When I use a PHP framework, such as Codeigniter, or use the following queries BEFORE selecting from the database, I see no problem on the pages

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

But now I'm neither using any kind of framework nor my libraries, i'm working in a company that had this project almost completely finished and I noticed that, when I save the accented characters as they are in the Database, for example, "Maçã" (apple in PT), they seem to be stored fine by MySQL (at least when I use phpMyAdmin to read the table) but are displayed badly by PHP/HTML. It looks like something similar to this:

**Ma< ?>< ?>**

This well known bad character with the question mark keeps coming everytime I echo these words on the code.

Is there any kind of configuration for MySQL or PHP that solves this problem (this specific one, i'm not talking about a general solution for charset) once for all so that I don't have to keep correcting it with different functions and hacks?

I have realized that `utf8_encode` on PHP side also solves this. But I wanted some kind  of configuration to be appended to my config.php or some sort of `ALTER TABLE`. Is there something out there?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the content is echoed INSIDE the DOM document and that the meta tag is properly set? if the content is echoed outside of the DOM it will not display it correctly. Also, mysql_* is deprecated, you should not use it any further for security reasons.

Comment: @briosheje alright, I know about the mysqli. thanks for the advice anyway. yes, I am 100% sure. I just changed the name of the table and field in this example I copied from the code `<p> <?php $r = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable'); while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) echo ($rr['myfield']); ?> </p>`

Comment: Yes but... where is that </p> placed? you have to be 100% sure that it is being printed inside the dom.. Also, your meta tag should be : `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Once you've echoed and you see that something is wrong, hit CTRL+U and check if the content is effectively INSIDE the DOM first

Comment: yes. I am sure. it is a webpage, and this problem happens from the navbar to the footer. the meta charset is correct as well. it doesn't seem to be a problem at client-side. if I put "ééé çççç ããããããã ~´ ¨¨¨" directly in the code, it works fine. if I use the utf8_encode or those queries, it also displays the characters right

Comment: Another thing that (might) be useful is this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php . If you're 100% sure that the code is being echoed correctly inside the DOM, if you are 100% sure that the meta tag is correct and 100% sure that the mysql character set is 'utf-8' and that mb_interal_encoding is utf-8 then please try http://php.net/manual/it/function.htmlspecialchars.php . If it still doesn't work I would kindly ask you to provide us a bigger piece of code in order to understand where the problem can be ;)

Comment: Sorry for /it/ link about htmlspecialchars, php took me there (since I'm italian), you can just replace /it/ with /en/ in the above link to find the english documentation :P

Comment: Perform `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to show us the hex for the naughty character. That will help decide whether the data is wrong in the database or the data is being processed incorrectly after fetching from the database.